# How to avoid the box in legend key when using aes(fill=kind) in both geom_bar and geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using aes(fill=kind) in both geom_bar and geom_smooth, I could not get a clean legend and the same plot as follows :
[image: Result I wish]

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

## load
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mma <- data.frame(kind=c(rep('A',100), rep('BB', 100), rep('CC',100)),
                  group=c(rep(seq(0.1, 10, by=0.1),3)),
                  frac=runif(n=300, min=0, max=1))

### pic
wd <- 0.05
posa <- position_dodge(width=wd)
ppa <- ggplot(data=mma, aes(x=group, y=frac, group=kind))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill=kind), stat='identity', position=posa, width=wd)+
    geom_smooth(aes(fill=kind, color=kind), method="loess", span=0.15, size=0.5)+
    labs(x="Time", y="Populations")+
    ## default   mina.png
    ## guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=3, byrow=TRUE), color="none")+    # minb.png
    ## guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=3, byrow=TRUE), fill="none")+    # minc.png
    theme(legend.position=c(0.66, 0.92),
          legend.key.size=unit(0.56, 'lines'))

### output
pf <- c(3, 7)
ggsave(file = "./mina.png", height = pf[1], width = pf[2])
```

- output of default setting (`mina.png`)
  [image: mina.png]
- disable color (`minb.png`)
  [image: minb.png]
- disable fill (`minc.png`)
  [image: minc.png]

I dont know why there is a blue line and a frame in the legend of `minb.png` (It seems if comes from `geom_smooth`).

I know the gray rect/box in `minc.png` could omit by using `alpha=1` in `geom_smooth`. However, it will also erase the span region of loess line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `show.legend = FALSE` in your `geom_smooth`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mma <- data.frame(kind=c(rep('A',100), rep('BB', 100), rep('CC',100)),
                  group=c(rep(seq(0.1, 10, by=0.1),3)),
                  frac=runif(n=300, min=0, max=1))

### pic
wd <- 0.05
posa <- position_dodge(width=wd)
ggplot(data=mma, aes(x=group, y=frac, group=kind))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=kind), stat='identity', position=posa, width=wd)+
  geom_smooth(aes(fill=kind, color=kind), method="loess", span=0.15, size=0.5, show.legend = FALSE)+
  labs(x="Time", y="Populations")+
  ## default   mina.png
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=3, byrow=TRUE), color="none")+    # minb.png
  ## guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=3, byrow=TRUE), fill="none")+    # minc.png
  theme(legend.position=c(0.66, 0.92),
        legend.key.size=unit(0.56, 'lines'))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, your results solve my problem. Meanwhile, is there any way to get a legend similar to choice B in the first picture? It seems another question, no colored box and keep span region in plot in `geom_smooth`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want a clean fill legend and color legend side-by-side as in your picture at the top of the question. In this case, you can achieve the effect using `guides`:

```r
ggplot(mma, aes(group, frac, fill = kind, color = kind)) +
  geom_col(position = posa, width = wd) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.15, size = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Populations", color = 'kind ') +
  guides(fill   = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NA, alpha = 1)),
         colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = 'white', alpha = 1))) +
  theme(legend.position  = c(0.66, 0.92),
        legend.key.size  = unit(0.56, 'lines'),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        legend.box       = 'horizontal')
```

[image]